# sql query runs two times with go

Tags: mysql, sql, go

I'm trying to setup a connection with MySQL server. As you can see I'm trying to make a simple insert but every time I run my program, it seems that it has run the INSERT query two times.

I run my program via command line `go run test_sql.go`.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Go MySQL Tutorial")

    // Open up our database connection.
    // I've set up a database on my local machine using phpmyadmin.
    // The database is called testDb
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:PASSWORD@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/test1")

    // if there is an error opening the connection, handle it
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    // perform a db.Query insert
    insert, err := db.Query("INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ( 1, 'TEST' )")

    // if there is an error inserting, handle it
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    // be careful deferring Queries if you are using transactions
    defer insert.Close()
    // defer the close till after the main function has finished
    // executing
    defer db.Close()
}
```

Comment: > it seems that it has run the INSERT query two times; How did you come to such conclusion?

Comment: i check it in database directly after each run with command line

Comment: Probably not the cause of your issue (but other than this your code looks OK to me) -  ```defer```s are run in a last-in-first-out order ([tour](https://tour.golang.org/flowcontrol/13)) so ```db.Close()``` will be called before ```insert.Close()``` which may cause an issue (I suspect it will be returning an error). Move the ```defer db.Close()``` above the ```db.Query``` line (the point being that the database connection should be closed regardless of what happens with the query). Note that ```db.Query``` should work but ```db.Exec``` is a better choice where there is no result set.

Comment: I found out running another example that it's not about the sql running two times. The whole programm runs in a differnt cmd window that opens and when it terminates it re-runs in the cmd window i wrote the command. So i need an answer for this.